# Limit search results to current folder

Tags: search

In WIN 10 Outlook O365 - When running a search in the "Current Folder" the search returns "Showing results from all folders. No results found in current folder ". How can I limit it to show results from only the "Current Folder" as requested and not other folders?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 Outlook Tools.

1. Outlook Options.

Set the Options for your starting folder and other options as you wish. Note that I have selected Current Folder when in Inbox. This works for me and you can experiment with Options.

[image]

2. Advanced Search.

When in the Inbox or other folder, click on Search (the Search bar at the top) to reveal the Search Ribbon.  From Search, you can pull down Search Tools and then access Advanced Find.

Advanced Find further allows you to browse to your folder and refine your search. You can also select Messages or other fields to find.

[image]

These are the main Outlook searching methods.

You should look in Control Panel, Indexing Options, and make sure Outlook by name is in Locations. You may wish to rebuild the Index if you make changes.

Index will include PST file (for local PST file POP Email) or OST file for Exchange or IMAP.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -2):

Your first suggestion is absolutely *not* what I want. When I search in Inbox I only want to search in Inbox, not the entire mailbox!

This is not an Indexing issue, it's a change that Microsoft made to Outlook 365 for some unknown reason. Since I first asked this question (over a year ago) I have found multiple conversations online with people complaining about this change, this is just one of many:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/stop-outlook-from-showing-results-from-all-folders/140ef9cf-c515-40b6-a134-75f96858acce

The only way to force it to return results from the specified folder is to add folder:"*foldername*" to the search string, which is absurd when you've already selected 'current folder' as a search parameter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).